# R-Studio SVM classAgreement how-to?

Tags: r, svm

I am an absolute newbie to R-Studio and want to use `svm()` of the [e1071](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-3) package. 
I went through David Meyer's [paper](https://datajobs.com/data-science-repo/SVM-in-R-[David-Meyer].pdf).

I can't get `classAgreement()` to run. 
What do I need to do before I can use `classAgreement()`?
Thanks a lot!

```
library(e1071)
data(Glass, package="mlbench")
index <- 1:nrow(Glass)
testindex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)/3))
testset <- Glass[testindex,]
trainset <- Glass[-testindex,]
svm.model <- svm(Type ~ ., data = trainset, cost = 100, gamma = 1)
svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, testset[,-10])
table(pred = svm.pred, true = testset[,10])
classAgreement(table)
```

Comment: your code works for me

Answer (score 0):

Running your code the `classAgreement(table)` throws the following error:

`Error in sum(tab) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument`

This is due to the fact that `table` here is a function as you didn't write an object called `table` which I think you intended to do in the previous line. 
So you can either do one of the following:

```
svm.tab <- table(pred = svm.pred, true = testset[,10])
classAgreement(svm.tab)
```

Or just in one go

```
classAgreement(table(pred = svm.pred, true = testset[,10]))
```